# Prove f(x)=glb{|x-a| : a in A} is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $A \subset R$, let $f(x)=glb{ |x-a| : a \in A}$

-Prove $f$ is well defined

-Prove $f$ is continuous

(Ok, here's the deal, because of the absolute value the greatest lower bound is always going to be $0$, so $f$ is constant, right? or am I missing something?

If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $A$ then $f$ is well defined and $f$ is continuous.

Can someone please tell me if I'm correct? Also I'm not sure how to write this formally.)

Comment: Basically your function measures the distance of a point $x$ from the set $A$.
Try to express $f(x)$ in terms of $f(y)$ where $y!=x$

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong, I have f(x)=glb{g(x)} where g(x)= |x-a|, then I don't understand, is the glb in terms of the function, or the set? I was taught about the glb's and lub's of sets.

Comment: The set $A$ is fixed. And $f$ measures how far a point $x$ is from the set (i.e. the 'smallest' distance to the set).

Comment: why should I use "y!"?

Comment: I meant $y$ not equal to $x$.
Refer to the definition of continuity...

Comment: A function f is continuous if for all a in A lim as x ->a of f(x)= f(a).

Comment: But there is an $\epsilon \delta$ formulation that would better suit here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $f(x)=glb{ |x-a| : a \in A}$

If $A$ is nonempty, since $|x-a|\geq 0 \quad \forall a\in A$, so $0$ is a lower bounded and the glb exists,  hence $f$ is well defined.

$\forall \epsilon >0$, by definition, $\exists a\in A$,s.t. $|x-a|<f(x)+\epsilon$. Then $f(y)\leq|y-a|\leq|x-a|+|x-y|<f(x)+\epsilon$ . Hence $f(y)-f(x)<|x-y|+\epsilon$

Let $\epsilon\to 0$, you get $f(y)-f(x)\leq |x-y|$

Similarly you can show $f(x)-f(y)\leq |x-y|$

Hence the function is Lipschitz, that is $\forall x,y,\in X, |f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$ Can you show it's continuous from here?

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean that a function is Lipschitz?

Comment: @Anne1 Here is a [definition](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)

Comment: (just to be clear, g(x)= |x-a| ? ) By eplsilon deltas, I can set d=E and that would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Anne1 What do you mean by $g(x)=|x-a|$? For second part, yes, give $\epsilon$, set $\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: in a previous comment I mentioned setting g(x)= |x-a|, since the function is f and you are using g's I'm not sure what you mean